# Converting C++ API Post Request into Delphi Code

Tags: delphi, code-conversion

I am programming in Delphi and I'm having a hard time converting a C++ API POST Request into delphi. I have tried using Indy as I have before with previous API's but this one seems to not work with whatever I try. Could someone help me with this?

**C++ Code I need to convert:**

```
CURL *hnd = curl_easy_init();

curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_URL, "https://sandbox.checkbook.io/v3/check/digital");

struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "accept: application/json");
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "content-type: application/json");
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Authorization: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"recipient\":\"testing@checkbook.io\",\"name\":\"Widgets Inc.\",\"amount\":5,\"description\":\"Test Payment\"}");

CURLcode ret = curl_easy_perform(hnd);
```

**Delphi Code that I have:**

```
unit API_InvoiceCloud;

interface

uses
  DB, SysUtils,  System.Classes, System.JSON, IdSSLOpenSSL, VCL.Dialogs,
  IdHTTP, XML.XMLIntf, xml.xmlDom, xml.XMLDoc, IDCoder, IDCoderMIME,
  IdBaseComponent, IdException{, IdZLibCompressorBase{, IdCompressorZLib{,Rest.Client};

procedure CreateDigitalPayment_CheckBookAPI(mRecipientEmailAddress,
                                      mRecipientName : String;
                                      mPaymentAmount : Double;
                                      mPaymentNumber,
                                      mPaymentDescription : String);


implementation

var
  { INDY COMPONENT TO CONNECT TO API SERVER; MAKES CONNECTION }
  IDHTTP1 : TidHttp;
  { SSL Connection }
  SSL : TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  { Request and Response vars }
  JsonRequest, InJson : String;
  JsonToSend : TStringStream;    //object to store json text and pass API
  JObj : TJSONObject;
Const
  { Constant variables holding the APIKEY+APISECRET and BASEURL }
  nBASEURL = 'https://sandbox.checkbook.io/v3/check/digital';
  nAPIKEY = 'xxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx';

procedure CreateDigitalPayment_CheckBookAPI(mRecipientEmailAddress,
                                            mRecipientName : String;
                                            mPaymentAmount : Double;
                                            mPaymentNumber,
                                            mPaymentDescription : String);
var
  { Response into String }
  SinglePartyResponse : String;
  ResponseCode : String;  
  { -----------Testing---------- }
  //lParamList: TStringList;
  nBASEURL : String;
  RequestBody : TStream;
  ResponseBody : String;
begin
  
  { JSON body with request string }
  JsonRequest := '{"recipient":"' + mRecipientEmailAddress
                + '","name":"' + mRecipientName
                + '","amount":' + FloatToStr(mPaymentAmount)
                + ',"number":"' + mPaymentNumber
                + '","description":"' + mPaymentDescription + '"}';
  
  try

    try
      { Create connection instance }
      IDHTTP1 := TidHttp.Create;

      { SSL Configuration }
      SSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create;
      SSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_1, sslvTLSv1_2];
      IDHTTP1.IOHandler := SSL;

      { Headers/Params }
      IDHTTP1.Request.Clear;
      IDHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.FoldLines := False;
      IDHTTP1.Request.Accept := 'application/json';
      IDHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
      IDHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := nAPIKEY;
      
      { Saving JSON text to TStringStream Object }
      JsonToSend := TStringStream.Create(JsonRequest, TEncoding.UTF8);
      //JsonToSend := TStringStream.Create(JsonRequest, TEncoding.ASCII);

      { Making POST Request using INDYs TidHTTP component; Params are: URL, JsonStringObj - saving into variable }
      SinglePartyResponse := IDHTTP1.Post(nBASEURL, JsonToSend);
      
      ShowMessage(IDHTTP1.ResponseCode.ToString);

    except
      on E : Exception do
        { Display error message if cannot do API CALL }
        begin
          ShowMessage(E.ClassName+' error raised, with message : "' + E.Message + '".');
          Abort;
        end
    end;

  finally
    { Free objects from memory }
    IDHTTP1.Free;
    SSL.Free;
    JsonToSend.Free;
  end;
  
end;

end.
```

When I try to make the POST request I get a 400 Bad Request error. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Change the endpoints to a server under your control and compare the requests?

Comment: cross-posted here: https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/7867-converting-c-api-post-request-into-delphi-code/

Comment: @Botje I do not have access to any of these servers to test this.

Comment: Hence "server under your control". Even your laptop suffices.

Comment: You don't need control over the server. Both curl and Indy have options to output the raw HTTP data that is being transmitted back and forth. Turn those options on. In curl, use [`CURLOPT_VERBOSE`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_VERBOSE.html). In Indy, assign a `TIdLog...` component to the `TIdHTTP.Intercept` property

Comment: Off-hand, the code looks correct, as far as `TIdHTTP` is concerned. So, the most likely culprit is the JSON  is probably malformed, ie if one of the text values has a `"` char in it. Since you have `System.JSON` in the `uses` clause, you really should use `TJSONObject` to create the JSON string, let it handle any necessary escaping as needed.

Comment: @Botje Pardon the ignorance, I am new to the language and API's. But thanks, I am giving that a try. I made a mock server in postman and will try what you recommended. I just need to figure out how to work this correctly too. HA.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks! And that's what I figured was wrong just wasn't too sure, so I will also try using the TJSONObject like suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found Solution. Thanks for the suggestions!

The 400 Bad Request Error was due to an "invalid authorization header"

My solution:

**1.** Went into the Embarcadero built in RestDebugger and got it to work in there by setting the **BASEURL**, **CONTENT-TYPE**, **AUTHORIZATION**(APIKey in Params), and **CustomBody**.

**2.** Clicked on the 'Copy Components' button and pasted `RESTClient`, `RESTRequest`, `RESTResponse` onto an empty form.

**3.** Built the JSON String and passed it as parameter to `RESTRequest.AddBody` then executed.(Code below)

```
    RESTRequest.AddBody(JsonStringRequest, ctAPPLICATION_JSON);
    RESTRequest.Execute();
    RESTResponse := RESTRequest.Response;
```

There are better ways to do this, but this worked for me.